# ¿Como puedo crear/obtener versión de compilado que incremente automáticamente?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, asp.net-core

He estado intentado obtener un numero o versión de compilado de mi proyecto, se conforma por una solución con tres proyectos en csharp, basados en dotnet core, lo que busco es alguna manera de que en cada vez que compile o recompile la solución completa, se vaya incrementando el valor de la versión, y que yo pueda utilizarla a la hora de imprimir en consola o similares, desde ya, muchas gracias.

*Ejemplo:*
Proyecto de Guillermo — version 1.0.35.4-main # 25/06/2020.
(Es solo un ejemplo, no busco ese nivel de detalle).

Comment: Mira [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356694/579895) a ver si te puede servir

Answer (score 0):

El archivo **AssemblyInfo.cs** contiene el atributo **AssemblyVersion**, puedes usar un asterisco en el número de compilación para que incremente automáticamente con el número de compilación:

```
[assembly:AssemblyVersion("1.2.*")]
```

La sintaxis del atributo es:
<versión principal >.<versión secundaria >.<número de compilación >.<revisión >

En tiempo de ejecución puedes obtener el número de versión

```
string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Si tu proyecto no cuenta con el archivo AssemblyInfo puedes generarlo siguiendo [éstos pasos.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138418/equivalent-to-assemblyinfo-in-dotnet-core-csproj#47075759)

Mas información:
[AssemblyVersionAttribute Clase en MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)